# STM32F4 I2C transmit return HAL_OK but not working

Tags: stm32, i2c, stm32f4

I’m using the board, motordriver IIC, to control motor through I2C bus.
The chip on the board is PCA9685.

The board is originally a extension for arduino UNO, and I’m using STM32F446RE which also support arduino UNO expansion connector.

The official give the arduino code, here is github link, and I would like to translate it into stm32 code using HAL library.

Now I want to drive a motor connect to M1 on the board with PWM 100%, but it doesn't work.

**Here is my code:**

```
#define driver_address 0x40<<1

#define LED0_ON_L 0x06
#define M1IN1 LED0_ON_L + 4 * 0
#define M1IN2 LED0_ON_L + 4 * 1
#define M1PWM LED0_ON_L + 4 * 2

uint8_t TX_Buffer_1[5] = {M1IN1, 4096, 4096>>8u, 0, 0>>8u};
uint8_t TX_Buffer_2[5] = {M1IN2, 0, 0>>8u, 4096, 4096>>8u};
uint8_t TX_Buffer_3[5] = {M1PWM, 0, 0>>8u, 4096, 4096>>8u};

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C_Init();
  device_exist = HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, driver_address, 10, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  while(1)
  {
    state1 = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, driver_address, TX_Buffer_1, 5, 10);
    state2 = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, driver_address, TX_Buffer_2, 5, 10);
    state3 = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, driver_address, TX_Buffer_3, 5, 10);
  }
}
```

**Here is the clock configuration setting:**

[clock_configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGEu1.png)

I tried the example code on arduino, and it works.
I use logic analyzer comparing the difference that arduino and stm32 show, the following is the result.

(the picture is the part of tranmitting TX_Buffer_1)

**when I use the HAL function：HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit()**
SDA line got some other HIGH signal between every byte
[comparing_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p03n5.jpg)

**when I use the HAL function：HAL_I2C_Mem_Write()**
SDA line data looks ok
but the problem is SCL line, there is no gap between every 9 bit
[comparing_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01UUH.jpg)

I think that's the problem why my I2C doesn't work, but I don't know how to figure it out...

Comment: You define arrays of `uint8_t` then try to initialise them with values like `4096`. I don't see how that will work. If it does work, it is very obscure.

Comment: I use arduino do the same thing and it works. Using logic analyzer to compare stm32 and arduino signal, I think the 4096 part is right,  you can see the picture "comparing_1" and "comparing_2".

Comment: Spikes every byte are normal for STM32. They're short high spikes on ACK bit, which the slave quickly pulls down to actually acknowledge stuff. I have similar ACK spikes on my STM32F103 here, and it works ok. It could be something else. And yes, you should remove all the 4096. you're working with 8-bit uints, max value is 255.